# Matrix $AB = 0$ , so $A$ and $B$ are not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to show that if a matrix $AB = 0$ , then the matrices $A$ and $B$ are not invertible.

Edit: Could we show the same thing with A and B =/ 0?

Comment: $det(AB)=det(A)det(B)$.

Comment: Note that it may be the case that one of $A$ and $B$ is invertible, but not both.  For example, if $A$ is the identity and $B$ is the all zeros matrix.

Comment: As was commented above the statement as written is not correct. You should change the statement "then the matrices $A$ and $B$ are not invertible" to something like "then $A$ and $B$ cannot both be invertible".

Answer (score 4):

If we assume that $A$ is invertible then it follows that

$$B = A^{-1}A B = A^{-1} 0 = 0$$

is not invertible. Likewise if we assume that $B$ is invertible then

$$A = A BB^{-1} = 0B^{-1} = 0$$

is not invertible.

Comment: Would there be someway to show the same thing with A and B =/ 0?

Comment: @MathStudent It already does. This argument shows that if either matrix is invertible then the other one has to be the (non-invertible) zero matrix. In other words: it is not possible to have $A$ or $B$ invertible and the other one not being the zero matrix.

Comment: @MathStudent If you are looking for an example not involving the zero matrices then take for example $AB = \left(\matrix{1 & 0\\ 0 & 0}\right)\left(\matrix{0 & 0\\ 0 & 1}\right) = \left(\matrix{0 & 0\\ 0 & 0}\right)$. Here neither $A$ nor $B$ are invertible (as the argument says they have to be).

Answer (score 2):

Use the relation $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$.

Comment: So AB is not invertible, only if det(A) = 0 or det(B) = 0, right ?

Comment: It is like a definition but it is easy to see since when you want to invert a matrix $A$, you need to compute $\det(A)^{-1}$

Comment: Understood, would there be someway to show the same thing with A and B =/ 0?

Comment: If $\det(AB) \not= 0$, then $\det(A) \not= 0 \land \det(B) \not= 0$ as you can see.